# how to run code in fragment only if it is visible to user

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have 4 fragments, in each one i want to use accelerometer that do different thing. My problem is that when i swipe to second fragment and shake my phone it runs code from first fragment because it is a part of same activity. I override onResume and onPause methods but it won't work right (only work when i swipe to fragment 3 than sensor is unregistered. I have tried something with if function inside onSensorChanged method and put some public static int fragmentPageNumber and change it onCreate method of every fragment but it is changed to fragment 2 when activity is started so i must then swipe thru fragments for code to start working right...but i think the problem is on overriding onResume and onPause methods right...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerEventListener, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelerometerEventListener);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on a few factors, you might be able to override [setUserVisibilityHint()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) in your `Fragments`. If your `Fragments` are added to a `FragmentPagerAdapter` or a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, these adapters will call this method on the `Fragment` when it becomes visible. In your case, in your `Fragments`, you could do something like:

```
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        sensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerEventListener, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    } else {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelerometerEventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for me tnx, i just added isVisibleToUser && accelerometerEventListener != null

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an extension function on Kotlin to run a block of code only when the fragment is attached to the **Activity**. So whenever the context is created u can be sure that the fragment has been attached to an activity and so shown to the user.

```
internal inline fun Fragment.runIfFragmentIsAttached(block: () -> Unit) {
    context?.let { block() }
}
```